# How to isolate and verify the source of optical absorption/effects?

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, condensed-matter, experimental-physics, solid-state-physics

This is similar to [my other question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/101316/optical-absorption-what-are-the-common-ranges-and-mechanisms), but not the same -- that one was about the energy ranges of various absorption mechanisms, and this one is more about experimental techniques to find them.

Let's assume you've taken transmission and reflection spectra from the mid-IR to the UV of a sample. It has various dips and peaks, to keep it very general.

Now of course you can use the information my previous question was about, for clues -- if an absorption peak occurs around 0.1eV, you might assume it's a phonon mode. But for most real samples, all these different effects are usually very broad, overlapping, of different relative magnitudes, and not at the exact places they are in this image:

[image]

So, how do you confirm that it's what you suspect, in the case of, for example, phonon absorption? What experimental techniques exist for isolating and confirming the other major absorption mechanisms too?